# CURL POST Request with Cookie Authorization

Tags: php, authentication, curl, session-cookies

I am trying to POST according to the following instructions:

**Resource Information**

HTTP Method: POST

Content-type: application/json

Accept: application/json

**Authentication**

*Note: Either a Cookie or Authorization header is required.*

Cookie: SESSION_ID=108259418ff689fc

Authorization: Basic WVdECUMScUZGGGBGOlhVODdGNXFkR253SA==

**Example Request**

POST https://sandbox.domain.com/api/authenticationTokens

Cookie: SESSION_ID=cdf5b882667d24a2

What is meant by "Either a Cookie or Authorization header is required." I don't understand how to read/interpret and implement the "Example Request".

Here is what I have so far:

```
    $parameters = array();

    $curl = curl_init();
    $header = array( "Accept: application/json", "Cookie: _SESSION_ID=cdf5b882667d24a2" );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sandbox.domain.com/api/authenticationTokens" );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, count( $parameters ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $parameters ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
    $response = curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );
```

Answer (score 1):

The example above is using cookie authentication. Cookies are sent in the request headers. To use cookie authentication you need to somehow obtain the session ID and substitute that into the code. I am guessing you need to somehow open a session previously and then use that value in the cookie, however that does seem like an odd way to authenticate for an API. Also, I'm not sure if the leading underscore is a typo or not. You might want to try it without the underscore if it doesn't work:

```
"Cookie: SESSION_ID=cdf5b882667d24a2"
```

Or, if you want to use HTTP authentication, you need to provide a username and password doing something like

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password' );
```

If all you have is a single value, it would probably go in the `password` part leaving the username blank:

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, ':WVdECUMScUZGGGBGOlhVODdGNXFkR253SA==' );
```

Comment: Is sending the Cookies in the request header as I did above different than using CURLOPT_COOKIE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR? Yes, the leading "_" is a typo.

Comment: Sending it manually as a header should be the same as sending `CURLOPT_COOKIE`, but if I were you, I would prefer using `CURLOPT_COOKIE`. `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` saves the cookies to a local file and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` I think sends the file instead of having to parse the file and call `CURLOPT_COOKIE` with the contents. See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php